# Did the "--ipv4-timeout" can work in the vlc Activex ? How?

Tags: timeout, activex, vlc

I want use the "--ipv4-timeout" option in the vlc activex,but it does not work,here is my code:

id = vlc.playlist.add(rtspURL, null, "--ipv4-timeout=20000");

Answer (score 0):

please try this

```
:network-caching=1000 :ipv4-timeout=25000
```

example:

```
var options = new Array(":network-caching=", ":ipv4timeout=25000"); 
vlc.playlist.add(mrl,"test",options); 
vlc.playlist.playItem(itemId);
```